# Getting setlistadapter to work

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app and I designing the Home layout which which is using fragments for contacts, messages and some other things. So on the contacts fragment I want to display a list of the persons contacts. I can get a listview working under a listactivity class but with this fragmentactivity I can't get it to work. I have an error that says "The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}" I just don't know what I need to modify to get this working.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FragTest extends FragmentActivity {  
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
    JSONParser jsonparser=new JSONParser();
    String userName;
    public static String url_friends="...";
    public static String url_id="...";

    /** 
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide 
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a 
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which 
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory 
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a 
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}. 
     */  
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;  

    /** 
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents. 
     */  
    ViewPager mViewPager;  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag_test);  

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        userName=SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(FragTest.this);
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three  
        // primary sections of the app.  
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.  
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);  

    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  
        return true;  
    }  

    /** 
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to 
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages. 
     */  
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
            super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.  
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class  
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.  
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();  
            Bundle args = new Bundle();  
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);  
            fragment.setArguments(args);  
            return fragment;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
            // Show 3 total pages.  
            return 3;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();  
            switch (position) {  
            case 0:  
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);  
            case 1:  
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);  
            case 2:  
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);  
            }  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  

    /** 
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply 
     * displays dummy text. 
     */  
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {  
        /** 
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this 
         * fragment. 
         */  
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";  

        public DummySectionFragment() {  
        }  

        @Override  
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);  
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1){
                dummyTextView.setText("Contacts");
            }
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2){
                dummyTextView.setText("Chat");
            }
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==3){
                dummyTextView.setText("Messages");
            }
            //dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));  
            return rootView;  
        }  
    }

    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        public LoadAllProducts(/*Context context, View rootView, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> llistatEntrades, ListView lv*/){

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            List<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",userName));
            JSONObject json=jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(url_id, "POST", param);
            Log.d("Ids", json.toString());

            List<NameValuePair> prm=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try {
                prm.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",json.getString("user_id")));
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            prm.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query","friends"));

            JSONObject jsn=jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(url_friends, "POST", prm);
            //Log.d("Friends", jsn.toString());
            try {

                JSONArray array = jsn.getJSONArray("options");

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                   // Log.i("name", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString("contact_id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String picture=c.getString("picture");
                    Log.i("picture_url", picture);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put("contact_id", id);
                    map.put("name", name);
                    map.put("picture", picture);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            FragTest.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "contact_id","name", "picture"},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.profilepicture });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a listview in your xml?

This might help:

```
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    final ListAdapter adapter;
    final ListView myList= getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    FragTest.this, productsList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "contact_id","name", "picture"},
                    new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.profilepicture });
            // updating listview
           myList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. yes I do have a listview in my xml. When I try out your code though, I get and error on getView, "undefined for type fragtest".

Comment: Try adding this above your oncreate: static Fragment testFragment;

then add this in your onCreateView: testFragment = this;

Then use it like this: 
  final ListView myList= testFrag.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);