# ListFragment doesn't show changes in present time

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

All! I'am new in android app. Now I have some problem.  I can't see the result of changing list  right away (after updating listView in my ListFragment). 
For example, i called method **addNewItem**  and I didn't see any changes on the screen. But if I touch ListFragment I will see all my changes.

**ListFragment:**

```
public class PointsListFragment extends ListFragment {

    PlaceItemsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new PlaceItemsAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.place_list_item,
                new ArrayList<PlaceItem>());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

   public void addNewItem(int id, String address) {
     adapter.items.add(new PlaceItem(id, address));
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    private class PlaceItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceItem> {

        private final int viewResourceId;
        final public ArrayList<PlaceItem> items;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public PlaceItem getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }

        public PlaceItemsAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId, ArrayList<PlaceItem> items) {
            super(context, viewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
            this.viewResourceId = viewResourceId;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(viewResourceId, null);
            }
            PlaceItem placeItem = getItem(position);
            TextView placeIdTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeId);
            placeIdTextView.setText(String.valueOf(placeItem.getId()));
            TextView placeAddressView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeAddress);
            placeAddressView.setText(placeItem.getAddress());
            if (selectedValue == position) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_item);
            }
            return v;
        }

    }
}
```

My activity xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"[enter image description here][1]
        android:padding="2dp">
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/forBorder"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:text="проложить маршрут"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            class="com.restfulrobot.cdcapplication.PointsListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_frag" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Image Example
[image: ListView Problem]

Comment: define this globally and why do you have nested class(each with a different parent)?
`final public ArrayList<PlaceItem> items;`

Comment: i think you have a [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689357/getting-setlistadapter-to-work)

Comment: What do i need to do?

Comment: he asked same question in 2013 and didn't get his answer, i think the easiest way to do is to start from beginning and change [this project](https://github.com/dmnugent80/CustomAdapter) to customize it

Comment: Hey from where are you calling `addNewItem` this method
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, ALL! I found the answer! I called method from another class (no Activity or Fragment). And now I also call method from another class, but i do it through Handler. And it really  works fine now!
Something like that:

```
 Message msg = mainActivityHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.NEW_MESSAGE, someObjectToAdd);
 mainActivityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```